# Show that if $\inf(A^+)=a>0$ then $a\in A$ and $A=\{za;z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

$A$ is a set such that $x,y\in A\Rightarrow$ $x-y\in A$, and $A^+$ is a subset of $A$ which contains only its positive elements.

I was able to successfully show that if $na\in A$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}, n \neq 0$ then $(na,na \pm a)\cap A=\emptyset$ and that if $infA^+=0$ then $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Not sure if the first the latter is useful in this context but I am leaving it here in case it is (maybe consider set $A-a$?).

Now, the only thing left for me to prove is that all $za\in A$ for $z\in \mathbb{Z}$. From what I've observed, it suffices to show that $a\in A$, but I have been stuck trying to prove that for a while with no success whatsoever.

If anyone could offer some help it would be highly appreciated. Please do not just give out the answer though. Some tip/insight to get me on the right track would be more interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe: $A$ is a group with addition:  Assume it is nonempty so $\exists x\in A$.

i) $x-x=0 \in A$

ii) If $x\in A$ then $0-x \in A$

iii) If $x,y\in A$ then $x+y=x-(-y)\in A$

Now the statement is basically saying discrete subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$ is cyclic:

Suppose your chosen $a\notin A$. Then there must be a sequence in $A$: $a_n\downarrow a$ by definition of $\inf$. Now consider the sequence $(a_n-a_m)_{m,n}$ to get a contradiction. (A convergent sequence is Cauchy)